# Flutter: Parameters are undefined

Tags: flutter

I have an error in the code that is saying that the passed parameters are undefined. i.e `The named parameter 'behavior' isn't defined.`
The specific parameters that are supposedly undefined are: `behavior`,               `horizontalDismissDirection`, `backgroundColor`, and `brightness`

this is the Flutter code:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flash/flash.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../generated/l10n.dart';
import '../../services/index.dart';

static Future<T?> toast<T>(String message) async {
    final context = await _buildCompleter.future;
    return showFlash<T>(
      context: context,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3),
      builder: (_, controller) {
        return Center(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
            child: Flash(
              controller: controller,
              position: FlashPosition.bottom,
              behavior: FlashBehavior.floating,
              horizontalDismissDirection: HorizontalDismissDirection.horizontal,
              backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
              brightness: brightness(context),
              child: FlashBar(
                content: Text(
                  message,
                  style: _contentStyle(context, Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            )
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

[image]

The code should compile as I have declared the neccesary files accordingly, I don't know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
class Flash<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  const Flash({
    Key? key,
    required this.controller,
    required this.child,
    this.position,
    this.dismissDirections = const [],
    this.forwardAnimationCurve = Curves.easeOut,
    this.reverseAnimationCurve = Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
    this.slideAnimationCreator = _defaultSlideAnimationCreator,
  }) : super(key: key);
...
}
```

Because these parameters are not defined for **Flash** but some of them are defined for **FlashBar**.

Check out the [Flash package Repository](https://github.com/sososdk/flash)